# Changing background color of a selected List item

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, listitem

I have a menu drawer with a list that has a custom ArrayAdapter. I wish to change the background color of a selected list item but I'm not sure how to. I tried changing it in my getView of the adapter, like how some others have suggested, but that didn't work, the background color is still unchanged.

Here's what I tried:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View myView = getItem(position).getView(mInflater, convertView);
  if (myView.isSelected())
    myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
  return myView;
}
```

Where should I be doing this, and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this just using `selector` as below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="#FFFFFF" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="#000000" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="#000000" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

And then use this selector as `background` of your list item layout as below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

    ........
    ........

<RelativeLayout/>
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried this, by creating a list_selector.xml in my drawable folder and copy/pasting your version into it, but can't seem to use absolute color values such as #FFFFFF or #000000. I get a build error "Error: Color types not allowed"

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(matchPosition.contains(new Integer(position))){
        TextView mvw = (TextView)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        mvw.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.litegreen));
    }
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

i use the above on entries in a list and working fine